# Dash Plotly error : Stuck on Loading... page after server run

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Could you please help me with this error.
The page stuck with loading.... message but never loads.

There's no error on server run.

This is my code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_csv('lines.csv', encoding='latin-1', low_memory=False)
df1.rename(columns={"Order Type": "OrderType"}, inplace=True)

df1.loc[(df1.Processed != '?'), 'OrderTypeProcessed'] = df1['Qty']
df1.loc[(df1.Processed == '?'), 'OrderTypeProcessed'] = 0

df2 = df1.groupby('OrderType').sum()
df3 = df1.groupby(' Packout station Number').sum()
df4 = df1.groupby('Packout station Operator').sum()
df5 = df1.groupby('Product Category').sum()
df1.rename(columns={df1.columns[12]:'Received Time'}, inplace=True)
df6 = df1.groupby('Received Time').sum()
df7 = df1.groupby('Cut Off Time').sum()




df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df3.reset_index(inplace=True)
df4.reset_index(inplace=True)
df5.reset_index(inplace=True)
df6.reset_index(inplace=True)
df7.reset_index(inplace=True)

df5['Product Category'] = df5['Product Category'].str.upper()

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1(children = "Dashboard Para Gestão De Produção - Caio",
    style = {'textAlign' : 'center',}),
        html.Div(children = "_______________________________",
                 style = {'textAlign' : 'center',}),

    dcc.Graph(
        id = 'lines-chart',
        figure = {
            'data' : [
        {'x': df2['OrderType'], 'y': df2['Qty'],                'type': 'bar', 'name': 'Dropado'},
        {'x': df2['OrderType'], 'y': df2['OrderTypeProcessed'], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'Realizado'}


            ],
            'layout' : {
                'title': 'Grafico'
            }
        }
    )

])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(port =4050)
```

Could you please take a look, I tried call assets in app, however it also didn't work.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppyzG.png) is the page after server run.

Comment: Did you ever solve or fix this?  I'm having the same issue running it behind a reverse proxy using apache.  It works great on local mode, but this happens when deploying with gunicorn behind a reverse_proxy.

Comment: @Kyle, same, any workaround so far?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the image that not load in question.

[image]